# Can I query MySQL to return the results in the same way I sent to a bulk select query?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a query:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE var IN (v1, v2, v3, v4) LIMIT 1
```

I would like the get back the first match he finds, in the order I sent them.
e.g. if the table has a row with var=v2 and also a different row with var=v4, that he will return the row with var=v2. I am aware I can of-course divide the query into many sub-queries but am interested if there is a different solution for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try,

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl 
WHERE var IN (v1, v2, v3, v4) 
Order By Field(var, v1, v2, v3, v4) 
LIMIT 1
```